# How do I make my react-redux app output to an index.js/html using webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, single-page-application

Currently my project works on `webpack-dev-server` which is already configured to run from my `react-redux` project(it was part of boilerplate so I am not sure how the dev-server is setup).

It has an `index.html` and this is able to run on the `dev-server` but somehow when I just load up the `index.html` by opening the file, it doesn't load anything.

I wanted webpack to give me a single index.html file which I could just open and run the project since the entire project is a single page app and just frontend.

I have seen this setup before for a single page app but I am not sure how to get webpack to do this.

Please help.

Comment: The boilerplate you're using probably has a build script (for production) in addition to the script you were using for development. Running that build script *should* output an index.html file and an associated JS bundle containing your app, already linked inside the generated index.html. If that's not the case, you're going to have to put together that build script yourself.

Comment: It does and running `npm build` runs webpack and creates bundle.js. I it loads that but gives error for some resource inside bundle.js. Somehow it is not built completely...